# Domino OSGI plugin - Couldn't find design note

Tags: java, lotus-domino, lotus

I am trying to creata a **Domino OSGI plugin** which exposes a simple Hello World servlet.
To do this I created in eclipse a plugin project(with web.xml and the servlet in place) , a feature project containing this plugin and an updated site project.

After this I created an application in Domino designer using the 'Eclipse Update Site' as template (name RestDemoUpdateSite.nsf).
With this application open in Domino administrator, I successfully imported my eclipse update site.

Finally I copied RestDemoUpdateSite.nsf to the folder -
 C:\Program Files\IBM\Domino\data and added the line OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES=RestDemoUpdateSite.nsf in notes.ini.

The link http://<>/RestDemoUpdateSite.nsf opens fine

A GET request to http://<>/RestDemoUpdateSite.nsf/api/ gives the json response

```
{
  "services":[
    {
      "name":"Data",
      "enabled":false,
      "version":"9.0.1",
      "href":"\/RestDemoUpdateSite.nsf\/api\/data"
    },
    {
      "name":"Calendar",
      "enabled":false,
      "version":"9.0.1",
      "href":"\/RestDemoUpdateSite.nsf\/api\/calendar"
    },
    {
      "name":"Core",
      "enabled":true,
      "version":"9.0.1",
      "href":"\/RestDemoUpdateSite.nsf\/api\/core"
    }
  ]
}
```

A GET request to my servlet http://<>/RestDemoUpdateSite.nsf/serviceapi/student gives the error

HTTP Web Server: Couldn't find design note - serviceapi/student [/RestDemoUpdateSite.nsf/serviceapi/student] Anonymous

Any suggestion or hints as to what might be going wrong would be of great help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to make sure your plugin is being loaded by the OSGi framework.  Execute the following server console command:

```
tell http osgi ss {bundle.name}
```

For example, `tell http osgi ss com.ibm.domino.services` lists all the plugins matching the given name.  The listing tells you whether a plugin is ACTIVE, RESOLVED, INSTALLED, etc.

Assuming your plugin is being loaded, the next step is to make sure you are defining your servlet correctly.  You said you included a web.xml file, but OSGi servlets are typically defined in plugin.xml.  They implement the `org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets` extension.  You can find more details in [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/fiorep/domino-osgi-development).  See the section starting with "Creating, deploying & debugging a simple servlet".

Comment: Thanks!! that slide helps a lot :)